# Macbook Pro runs very hot when using VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtualbox, macbook-pro

I am using a Macbook Pro and switch to running a Windows VM through VirtualBox for some work I am doing for a client.

I notice that, very quickly, the Macbook heats up to extremely hot temperatures (just touching the case is almost hot enough to start hurting). Has anybody else run into this issue? Are there any resolutions to fixing it? I know the Mac can technically handle it, but I don't like mixing heat and my computer - especially for multiple hours a day.

**Edit**

I want to be clear (since I wasn't above). The MacBook runs at normal temperatures when I run anything else. The **only** time it gets hot is when I use VirtualBox running Windows. (Even VBox running Linux VMs is fine.)

Comment: I suggest trying a cooling fan.  Clearly its pushing the limits of the machine more then you realize.  When was the last time you cleaned out the dust?

Comment: @Ramhound The machine is brand new. Like...two days old brand new. And, I will be traveling with this machine a lot - can't have much (anything external). And, won't open it up so I don't void the warranty.

Comment: I would take it to an Apple store to see what they say.  Your laptop shouldn't get that warm, laptops of course, have not been designed for "lap" usage for years.

Comment: @Ramhound - I updated my question. I wasn't clear. The laptop ONLY gets hot running Windows 7 in a VM. No other time.

Comment: I've had this same problem on my Ubuntu laptop running Windows in a VM in VirtualBox.  Windows doesn't play nice.  It's a hog.  I bought a laptop cooler that has two 1" flip-out legs underneath on the bottom to allow cool air to circulate underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had instances where my MacBook runs pretty hot with either VMs or intensive applications. My answer was to install [smcFanControl](http://www.eidac.de) which installs a menubar icon where I can monitor the temperature and turn up the fan either before I run a VM or when it gets hot.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Thank you. A quick question I would have is - shouldn't OSX already handle spinning up and down the fans as necessary?

Comment: Well the Macbook was designed so that the fan is as quiet as possible while being within tolerances. Usually I can not audibly hear the fan until the temperatures get to about 90 degree C. Without smcFanControl it is not uncharacteristic for temperatures to reach 100 C, so while it is still within the engineering tolerance...it's hot to touch.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Tried out the fan control yesterday and it seems to do the trick. Ran at a cool (but slightly louder) 48 C. Thanks!